# Skew normal distribution mathematical representation

Tags: normal-distribution

```
skewnorm.pdf(x, a) = 2 * norm.pdf(x) * norm.cdf(a*x)
```

skewnorm takes a real number  as a skewness parameter When a = 0 the distribution is identical to a normal distribution (norm).
[Reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html)

I want to present this in mathematical form.
I am having trouble writing `norm.cdf(a*x)` .So here's my input.

`skewnorm.pdf(x, a)`$=\frac{2}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} }e^{-\frac{(x-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma^2  }} \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{t}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} }e^{-\frac{(ax-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma^2  }}dt$

Did I write it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) gives
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{2}{\omega \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{2\omega^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha (\frac{x-\xi}{\omega})}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} d t
\end{equation}
Obviously, their $\xi, \omega$ are your $\mu,\sigma$. If one substitutes $t=\alpha \frac{u-\xi}{\omega}$ in the integral, it gives
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{2}{\omega \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{2\omega^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{\alpha}{\omega\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\alpha^2\frac{(u-\xi)^2}{2\omega^2}} d u
\end{equation}
If you want to use $\xi$ and $\omega$ in the scipy function, use the 'loc' and 'scale' parameters as described in the documentation.

Comment: How come $\alpha \frac{u-\xi}{\omega}$ is upper limit ?

Comment: It comes from the definition $f(x)= \frac{2}{\omega}\phi(\frac{x-\xi}{\omega})\Phi(\alpha\frac{x-\xi}{\omega})$